Debit and credits reconcile to knock off the transactions
I have transactions where we need to pay the vendor and also have transactions where we need to collect from the same vendor. I want to knock off the major transactions where the debit and credits should match with least variance like + or - 5 dollars. I have debits as separate data frame and credit as separate data frame. Could you please suggest some code to solve this. Thank you
enter image description here
Output
enter image description here
I thought of doing clustering but on what basis am not sure.

Hi there! Is this question about some kind of spreadsheet application? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
